# How to determine optimal value in R - Optimization problem

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, solver

I have below data frame that show sales (in unit) for 4 products for Q1. Each product has a maximum growth rate for Q2 and cost per hundred extra units.

Given a budget of 40000, what is the optimal growth rate for each product to maximize extra units sold?

I would appreciate if someone can help me with general solution which can be applied to similar problem with more constrains and product lines.

```
test.data = data.frame(
    PRODUCT_ID = c(1,2,3,4),
    Q1_SALE = c(12372125,400000,26116912,10000),
    COST_PER_HUNDRED_EXTRA_UNITS_SOLD = c(4,8,15,3),
    MAXIMUM_GROWTH_RATE = c(0.33,0.21,0.28,0.36),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think the best general advice is: (1) Define your objective function. (2) Look at `help("optim")`. (3) Come back to Stack Overflow and ask a focused question once you've tried an implementation if you run into any issues.

Comment: Growth rates are not additive so there are some conceptual questions to answer first.